# Docker start Apache2 and add mount point priviligies

Tags: docker

I am building an image for development purposes for my Symfony app and I have a problem to setup permissions correctly.

Here is the image

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

EXPOSE 443
ARG USERID

# Install PHP and PHP extensions, httpd
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php && \
     apt-get update && \
     apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
     software-properties-common \
     git \
     unzip \
     curl \
     php5.6 \
     apache2 \
     ...

# composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer


COPY ./docker/certificates/. /cert
COPY ./docker/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
COPY ./docker/php5.6-fpm.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available
RUN a2enmod headers \
    && a2enmod ssl \
    && a2enconf php5.6-fpm.conf \
    && a2ensite httpd.conf

# starts apache in foreground
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

And here is compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  mt_symfony:
    container_name: mt_symfony
    build:
      context: ./html
      dockerfile: dev.dockerfile
      args:
        - USERID=${USERID}
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/project
```

So briefly I mount my project directory to `/var/www/project`. Once docker-compose is done, I go to the container bash and run `composer install` manually.

The problem is that Symfony keeps giving me permission error, it can't create or write to cache folder.

I tried to add the following code (USERID is set to 1000, which is UID of my host user)

```
RUN useradd -u $USERID -d /var/www/project -s /bin/sh local
USER local
```

But then Apache2 fails to start because of permission error. It seems that Apache2 can only start from `root`.

Basically I want to be able to edit code that I shared through the mount point.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is something you will have to live with. Chmoding with 777 in the dev env is perfectly fine. I do this all the time on the var directory (with `-R` recursively). I have dozens of dockerized Symfony apps. As soon as you have any root owned files (eg. in the config directory because Flex put'em there, just chown 'em to make them yours. This is a one-time thing usually: `chown 1000:1000 config -R` in the container.

Otherwise you can run the Apache container with the `APACHE_RUN_USER` / `APACHE_RUN_GROUP` to match your UID (eg. `1000`). But you have to create the user in the Dockerfile first. Nevertheless Apache has to start as `root`.

To be honest: this permission issue doesn't bother me.

---

Remember to clean up your image:

```
# Clean up image
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

---

Always comment your `Dockerfile`, this file is code as any other, you want it clean, concise and well maintained. Every line should be documented why it's there and what's its role.